# Definition of symmetric relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I know that the relation is symmetric if $\forall x \forall y \  xRy \implies yRx $.

Consider the set $ A = \{{a, b, c, d}\}$
and 
$R = \{{(a, a),(a, b),(a, d),(b, a),(b, b),(c, c),(d, a),(d, d)}\}.$

My textbook claims that this relation is symmetric. But what about $(c,d)$ and $(d,c)$ that are not part of the $R$ set? In the definition, it said for all $x$ and $y$, so shouldn't this violate the symmetricity?

Comment: There is a typo in your first line. (Or maybe it's not a typo but a mistake - which would explain your confusion about the given example.)

Comment: @StefanMesken Thanks a lot! I edited it. It is still confusing me though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $(c,d)$ is in the relation, then we check whether $(d,c)$ is in the set.

However, in this case, $(c,d)$ is not in $R$, hence we should not expect $(d,c)$ to be in the relation for it to be symmetric.

Comment: Oh of course. So the interpretation is for all x and y that are in that R set. It doesn't necessarily require the relationship to be between all of the elements in set A?

Comment: yes, it is not required.

Comment: Thank you! I am so amazed how quickly the community here helps you out. This is great :)

Answer (score 2):

Definition 1: A relation R over set A is symmetric if for all x, y from A the following is true: 
(x,y) is in R implies (y,x) is in R.

Definition 2: A relation R over set A is symmetric if for all x, y from A the following is true: 
if (x,y) is in R, then  (y,x) is in R.

These definitions do not require that every (x,y) has to be in R. They only require that for those (x,y) that are in R, (y,x) has to be in R.

Suppose that no single (x,y), where x is different from y, is in R. In this case R is symmetric.

This is so because proposition

```
  if (x,y) is in R, then  (y,x) is in R
```

is automatically true when proposition

```
  (x,y) is in R
```

is false (i.e. when (x,y) is not in R).

Comment: Right now, your answer is a bit difficult to read, as the mathematics is poorly formatted.  It could be vastly improved with a little [MathJax code](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (and, perhaps, one or two fewer newlines).

Answer (score 0):

So $(a,c)$ is not included in $\mathbb{R}$. So we can not expect $(c,a)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

If $(a,c)$ is included in $\mathbb{R}$. So we can expect $(c,a)$ in $\mathbb{R}$

And so both are symmetric

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange. A quick tour of the site (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most of your time here. For typesetting your equations, please use MathJax:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference